# Change the subject of the email - Form module

Tags: reactjs, axios, cockpit-cms

I'm developing a website with Cockpit and React JS.

In this project, there is a very simple contact form (name, email, message).

I created a form in Cockpit, via the Forms module, and I added a configuration file in Cockpit (config/config.yaml) :

```
mailer:
  from: no-reply@***.com
  transport: smtp
  host: smtp.ionos.fr
  user: bonjour@***.com
  password: ***
  port: 587
  auth: true
  encryption:
```

The form module is configured to record data in Cockpit, but also to send me an email as soon as a new record is added (in plain language, as soon as a user clicks on the submit button on the form). That's why I had to create the config/config.yaml file with this informations.

Everything works perfectly. The datas are well recorded in Cockpit and I receive the email.

But I have a problem.

I want to change the subject of the email. For the moment, when I receive an email the subject is : "New form data for: Contact".

In the modules/Forms/bootstrap.php file, line 325... I found this :

```
$response = $this->app->mailer->mail($frm['email_forward'], $options['subject'] ?? "New form data for: {$formname}", $body, $options);
```

So, it's in this file that the subject of the email is managed. So, in theory, it's possible to pass an option to modify the subject of the email.

The problem is, I don't see how I should go about sending this information.

I have tried adding the information to the config/config.yaml file but it doesn't work. Like this :

```
mailer:
  from: no-reply@***.com
  subject: test /* <= I added this information */
  transport: smtp
  host: smtp.ionos.fr
  user: bonjour@***.com
  password: ***
  port: 587
  auth: true
  encryption:
```

[On this page](https://github.com/agentejo/cockpit/issues/221), it's indicated that it's necessary to create a hidden field named "__mailsubject" and with as value the desired subject. The problem is that I'm using React JS (+ axios) and not PHP (no access to : $_REQUEST, $_POST, ...).

Here is the code my React component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Form extends Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onChangeName = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onChangeEmail = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onChangeMessage = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmitForm = this.onSubmitForm.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            message: ''
        }
    }
    
    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    onSubmitForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        const dataForm = {
            "form": {
                name: this.state.name,
                email: this.state.email,
                message: this.state.message
            }
        };
        
        axios
            .post('http://dev.site.com/api/forms/submit/contact?token=XXX', dataForm)
            .then((res) => {console.log(res.data)} )
            .catch((error) => {console.log(error)} );

        this.setState({
            name: '', 
            email: '', 
            message: ''
        })
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="form">
                    <div className="title">{this.props.title}</div> 
                    <div className="content">
                        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitForm}>                         
                            <label htmlFor="name">Your name :</label>
                            <input name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.onChangeName} type="text" />
                            
                            <label htmlFor="email">Your email :</label>
                            <input name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onChangeEmail} type="text" />
                            
                            <label htmlFor="message">Your message :</label>
                            <textarea name="message" value={this.state.message} onChange={this.onChangeMessage}></textarea>
                            
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

I tried this. But it doesn't work :

```
        const dataForm = {
            "form": {
                __mailsubject: "test",
                name: this.state.name,
                email: this.state.email,
                message: this.state.message
            }
        };
```

PS: I will use later Formik and Yup to create and validate the form.

I don't see how I can achieve what I want, other than directly changing the modules/Forms/bootstrap.php file ! But this isn't a good solution because it will give me problems during updates !

The only solution is to use the form templates, [like here](https://discourse.getcockpit.com/t/edit-e-mail-template-in-forms/1233/2) ?

An idea ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to update the mail subject you need to pass the value as parameter and not as form data.

On your request you should have something like:

```
axios
  .post('http://dev.site.com/api/forms/submit/contact?token=XXX&__mailsubject=My email subject', dataForm)
  .then((res) => {console.log(res.data)})
  .catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
```

The code for this can be seen at `modules/Forms/Controller/RestApi.php`

```
if ($this->param('__mailsubject')) {
   $options['subject'] = $this->param('__mailsubject');
}
```

This means it will only check for `__mailsubject` as a parameter value and not as a form data value.